# How to give permissions to uwsgi to read a folder?

Tags: command-line, permissions, chown, uwsgi

I am trying to give permissions to uwsgi to read a folder where my django project lives. I have tried the following command:

```
chown -R root:uwsgi /home/myproject/mysite
```

But I am getting this error:

```
chown: invalid group: ‘root:uwsgi’
```

Could someone help me understand why this happens? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The chown command changes the user and/or group of the folder or file.

If you want to give a user / group the permission to read you should use the chmod command. If you want to change the owner this is the correct synopsis, make sure you get the order of owner and group right.

```
 chown [OPTION]...[OWNER][:[GROUP]
```

Make sure that the group **uwsgi** actually exists.

You can check this by executing the command `sudo cat /etc/group | grep "uwsgi"`

If your group exists and the error persists, check for spelling mistakes.

Good luck :)